# git hook to update changes to working directory and bare git directory

Tags: git

I know how to clone and push (write) changes to a bare repository on a production server.

But how are these changes reflected in the production working directory?

I have used other SCLM for years, in those you checked the file out from production server and pushed your changes directly to the production server.

Can git perform a similar "auto-deploy" functionality?  If so how?

Comment: Simple answer: No.  Complex answer:  Yes (with hooks).

Answer (score 0):

Git does not have any built-in functionality for this, but does provide hooks to plug in this type of functionality. A git post-receive hook will be appropriate for your use case:

https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks

This link may also provide more useful information and scripts specific to your question: http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto.

Comment: I just red about hook.We can achieve the above purpose.But I am in no mood of writing my own version control :p.

Comment: The purpose of version control is not to deploy things but to manage versions. That is why git does not do this itself, but instead allows you to delegate this type of functionality to external hook programs. Always use the right tool for the job.

Comment: Make sense..Could u pls tel me some hook to update my working directory after every push.

Comment: If you see the link I posted in the answer, it provides one solution.