# git hook post receive is not working

Tags: git

**Background**:

I set post-receive hook on my server bare repo

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 midnight midnight   58 Jan 24 19:45 post-receive

$ cat post-receive 
GIT_WORK_TREE = /var/www/mongo_conprima git checkout -f
```

file permission of `/var/www/mongo_conprima`

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 midnight midnight     4096 Jan 25 08:40 mongo_conprima
```

**Porblem**
I get following error when I push from local host

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 228 bytes, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: hooks/post-receive: 1: hooks/post-receive: GIT_WORK_TREE: not found
```

I want to update production directory after each push on server [question]:[git hook to update changes to working directory and bare git directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338855/git-hook-to-update-changes-to-working-directory-and-bare-git-directory)

Answer (score 2):

What you have is a shell-script syntax problem rather than a git problem.

In a shell script:

```
a b c
```

runs command `a` with arguments `b` and `c`.  This is true even if you replace `b` with `=`, which just runs command `a` with arguments `=` and `c`.  So this is trying to run the command `GIT_WORK_TREE`, with arguments `=`, `/var/www/mongo_conprima_a`, `git`, `checkout`, and `-f` (in that order).

The shell script syntax for setting an environment variable and then running a command is:

```
VAR=value cmd args...
```

In short, you need to remove the spaces before and after the `=` sign.